# MySQL optimisation needs explaination

Tags: mysql, sql, optimization

I needed to get values from the "latest" (i.e. highest record id) record for each value of a field (`server_name` in this case).

I had already added a `server_name_id` index on `server_name` and `id`.

My first attempt took minutes to run.

```
SELECT server_name, state
FROM replication_client as a
WHERE id = (
  SELECT MAX(id) 
  FROM replication_client 
  WHERE server_name = a.server_name)
ORDER BY server_name
```

My second attempt took 0.001s to run.

```
SELECT rep.server_name, state FROM (
  SELECT server_name, MAX(id) AS max_id
  FROM replication_client
  GROUP BY server_name) AS newest,
replication_client AS rep
WHERE rep.id = newest.max_id
ORDER BY server_name
```

What is the principle behind this optimisation?  (I'd like to be able to write optimised queries without trial and error.)

P.S. Explained below:

```
mysql> EXPLAIN
    ->
    ->   SELECT server_name, state
    ->   FROM replication_client as a
    ->   WHERE id = (SELECT MAX(id) FROM replication_client WHERE server_name = a.server_name)
    ->   ORDER BY server_name
    -> ;
+----+--------------------+--------------------+------+----------------+----------------+---------+-------------------+--------+-----------------------------+
| id | select_type        | table              | type | possible_keys  | key            | key_len | ref               | rows   | Extra                       |
+----+--------------------+--------------------+------+----------------+----------------+---------+-------------------+--------+-----------------------------+
|  1 | PRIMARY            | a                  | ALL  | NULL           | NULL           | NULL    | NULL              | 630711 | Using where; Using filesort |
|  2 | DEPENDENT SUBQUERY | replication_client | ref  | server_name_id | server_name_id | 18      | mrg.a.server_name |  45050 | Using index                 |
+----+--------------------+--------------------+------+----------------+----------------+---------+-------------------+--------+-----------------------------+

mysql> explain  
    ->   SELECT rep.server_name, state FROM (
    ->     SELECT server_name, MAX(id) AS max_id
    ->     FROM replication_client
    ->     GROUP BY server_name) AS newest,
    ->   replication_client AS rep
    ->   WHERE rep.id = newest.max_id
    ->   ORDER BY server_name
    -> ;
+----+-------------+--------------------+--------+---------------+----------------+---------+---------------+------+---------------------------------+
| id | select_type | table              | type   | possible_keys | key            | key_len | ref           | rows | Extra                           |
+----+-------------+--------------------+--------+---------------+----------------+---------+---------------+------+---------------------------------+
|  1 | PRIMARY     | <derived2>         | ALL    | NULL          | NULL           | NULL    | NULL          |    2 | Using temporary; Using filesort |
|  1 | PRIMARY     | rep                | eq_ref | PRIMARY       | PRIMARY        | 4       | newest.max_id |    1 |                                 |
|  2 | DERIVED     | replication_client | range  | NULL          | server_name_id | 18      | NULL          |   15 | Using index for group-by        |
+----+-------------+--------------------+--------+---------------+----------------+---------+---------------+------+---------------------------------+
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, the whole thing is quite self-explaining, when you look at two words in your first explain plan: `DEPENDENT SUBQUERY`

This means, that for every row, your `where` condition examines, the subquery is executed. Of course this can be slow as hell.

Also note, that there's an order of operations when executing a query.

```
FROM clause
WHERE clause
GROUP BY clause
HAVING clause
ORDER BY clause 
SELECT clause
```

When you can filter in `FROM` clause, it's better than filtering in `WHERE` clause...